# Проверка resize однократно

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        console.log(1)
    }
    else {
        console.log(2)
    }
})
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы проверка происходила однократно при переходе брейкпоинта, в одну и в другую сторону. То-есть

Comment: Надо ставить таймаут. Почитайте во это: . https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661171/220220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  var oldWidth = $(window).data("oldwidth");
  var newWidth = $(window).width();
  console.log(oldWidth + " - " + newWidth);
  if (newWidth != oldWidth) {
    if (newWidth < 768 && (!oldWidth || oldWidth >= 768)) {
      console.log(1)
    } else if (newWidth >= 768 && (!oldWidth || oldWidth < 768)) {
      console.log(2)
    }
    $(window).data("oldwidth", newWidth);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```